# Not able to understand the function's behavior

Tags: javascript

Not able to understand the function's behavior

```
function Animal() {
    console.log("showing an empty string: " + name);
    console.log("showing not defined: " + other);
}

Animal("Tommy");
```

Comment: How does it behave ? How do you expect it to behave ?

Comment: The `function` you are calling is not what you have `defined`.. The `function` you defined doesn't accept any `param`.. So you will get `undefined error` in `console`..

Comment: Please be more specific with your question

Comment: What you are not understanding, do you get any errors or is it not working as expected ? be more specific about what you are not understanding

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions if you have any doudt in this explanation ask question then it will be more specific maheshv

Comment: In your case the function is not accepting any arguments as input so the value will be undefined if you try to send a value(arguments) also function is not ready to take that value.

Comment: I find "name" is showing an (empty string) and "other" is showing an error(other is not defined). So I am not able to understand Why "name" is not showing an error?.

Answer (score 3):

Since your function does not take any parameters, than executing

```
console.log("showing an empty string: " + name);
```

will result in

```
showing an empty string:
```

While executing

```
console.log("showing not defined: " + other);
```

will result in error "ReferenceError: other is not defined".

That behavior is because you are using global variables and every window has defined name. By default it's "" (empty string).

So if you open console and write `window.name` you will get `""` 
and if you write `window.other` you will get *`undefined`*

Comment: (y). Thank you very much. Justinas. understood :). Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

So every `window` has a `name` property mainly accessible by `window.name`.

So when you are calling that function, the first line is printing

```
showing an empty string:
```

Because usually name is an empty variable, and in the second line the variable `other` is not defined so it is throwing the error.